# jQuery delete class after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have viewer of objects with a switcher of list view and grid view. I also made if statement which says that when user choose grid view and in description is more than 35 characters user see only 35 characters, but when user back to list view I want it to comeback to full description. Can you have any solution for that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.switcher").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var mainId = $(this).attr("id");
    var classNames = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    var companyView = $("ul#company");
    var linkList = $('span#link-list');
    var gridDescription = $('span.description');
    var listDescription = $('span.meta');

    if (mainId == "gridview") {
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $("#listview").removeClass("active");

      companyView.removeClass("list");
      companyView.addClass("grid col-xs-12");
      linkList.addClass("links-position");

      gridDescription.addClass('.restrict');
      var txt = $('.description').text();

      if (txt.length > 35 && mainId == "gridview") {
        $('.description').html(txt.substring(0, 35) + ' <a class="morelink" href="">[...]</a>');
      }
      
      $(".morelink").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $("#gridview").removeClass("active");
        $("#listview").addClass("active");

        companyView.removeClass("grid col-xs-12");
        companyView.addClass("list");
        linkList.removeClass("links-position");
      });
    } else if (mainId == "listview") {
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $("#gridview").removeClass("active");
      companyView.removeClass("grid col-xs-12");
      companyView.addClass("list");
      linkList.removeClass("links-position");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  color: #333;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

img {
  border: 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

#wrap header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#wrap header .list-style-buttons {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.switcher {
  color: red;
}

.switcher:active {
  color: #da1d15;
}

.switcher:visited {
  color: #da1d15;
}

ul.list {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.list li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
}

ul.list li section.left {
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

ul.list li .meta {
  display: block;
}

ul.list li .links {
  display: inline;
}

ul.list li .secondOffer {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

ul.list li section.left img.thumb {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
}

ul.list li section.left h3 {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

ul.list section.left {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.grid {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.grid li section.left img.thumb {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

ul.grid li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 270px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.grid li section.left {
  padding: 10px;
}

ul.grid section.left {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}

.links-position {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

ul.grid li.clearfix {
  margin-bottom: 300px;
}

ul.grid li section.left h3 {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

ul.grid li .meta {
  display: block;
}

ul.grid li .address {
  position: relative;
}

ul.grid li .description {
  position: absolute;
}

ul.grid li .links {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

ul.grid .clearfix {
  padding: 10px;
}

.clearfix {}

section.left {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

section.left:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(207, 168, 168, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(207, 168, 168, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(207, 168, 168, 1);
}

a:link {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.links:visited {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.morelink {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap" class="col-xs-12">
  <header>
    <span class="list-style-buttons">
      <a href="#" id="listview" class="switcher"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-th-list"></i></a>
      <a href="#" id="gridview" class="switcher active"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-th"></i></a>
    </span>
  </header>
  <ul id="company" class="list clearfix">
    <li class="clearfix alt">
      <section class="left">
        <img src="" alt="company image" class="thumb">
        <a href="">
          <h3>Name</h3>
        </a>
        <span class="meta address"><strong>Address: </strong></span>
        <span class="meta description">
          DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION 
DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION
DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION
DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION
DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION 
        </span>
        <span id="link-list">
          <a href="" class="links">
            <i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i>
            Users: 
          </a>
          <a href="" class="links secondOffer">
           <i class="fa fa-database"></i> 
           Offers: 
          </a>
       </span>
      </section>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to store the original `description` somewhere to make the rollback.

Comment: but do you have any idea how to find that?

Comment: Konrad, check my answer, let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you for help, your solution really works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store a lot of things inside jQuery's `data` storage (which is aligned with the HTML5 `data` attribute, but not *directly connected*).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        //`bind` is deprecated, use `on`:
        $("a.switcher").on("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var mainId = $(this).attr("id");
            var classNames = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
            var companyView = $("ul#company");
            var linkList = $('span#link-list');
            var gridDescription = $('span.description');
            var listDescription = $('span.meta');

            if (mainId == "gridview") {

                $(this).addClass("active");

                $("#listview").removeClass("active");

                companyView.removeClass("list");
                companyView.addClass("grid col-xs-12");
                linkList.addClass("links-position");

                gridDescription.addClass('.restrict');
                
                //store local description:
                var $description = $(".description");

                $.each($description, function(i, e){
     var $thisDesc = $(this);
     var txt = $thisDesc.text();
     $thisDesc.data("full-desc", txt);
  
     if (txt.length > 35 && mainId == "gridview") {                    
      $thisDesc.html(txt.substring(0, 35) + ' <a class="morelink" href="">[...]</a>');
     }
    });

                //the .morelink a tag is being generated, you were trying to assign a listener *to that link*, but it doesn't exist yet, instead add a listener to a parent element that *will exist* on page load:
                $("#company").on("click", ".morelink", function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    
                    $("#gridview").removeClass("active");
                    $("#listview").addClass("active");
                    
                    //is this where you want to restore the full description?  Whenever you want, you can then pull the full description from the data-full-desc field, like this:
                    var $description = $(this).parents("li").find(".description");
                    $description.html($description.data("full-desc"));
                    
                    companyView.removeClass("grid col-xs-12");
                    companyView.addClass("list");
                    linkList.removeClass("links-position");
                });


            } else if (mainId == "listview") {

                $(this).addClass("active");


                $("#gridview").removeClass("active");

                companyView.removeClass("grid col-xs-12");
                companyView.addClass("list");
                linkList.removeClass("links-position");

                //restore descriptions:
                $.each($(".description"), function(i, e){
                    if(!!$(this).data("full-desc"))
             $(this).html($(this).data("full-desc"));
    });
            }

        });
    });
```

```css
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    color: #333;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

img {
    border: 0;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}



#wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

#wrap header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#wrap header .list-style-buttons {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.switcher {
    color: red;
}

.switcher:active {
    color: #da1d15;
}

.switcher:visited {
    color: #da1d15;
}


ul.list {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.list li {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
}

ul.list li section.left {
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

ul.list li .meta {
    display: block;

}

ul.list li .links {
    display: inline;
}

ul.list li .secondOffer {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

ul.list li section.left img.thumb {
    margin: 10px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
}

ul.list li section.left h3 {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

ul.list section.left {
    padding: 20px;
}


ul.grid {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.grid li section.left img.thumb {
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

ul.grid li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 270px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.grid li section.left {
    padding: 10px;
}

ul.grid section.left {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
}

.links-position {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

ul.grid li.clearfix {
    margin-bottom: 300px;
}

ul.grid li section.left h3 {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

ul.grid li .meta {
    display: block;
}

ul.grid li .address {
    position: relative;
}

ul.grid li .description {
    position: absolute;
}

ul.grid li .links {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

ul.grid .clearfix {
    padding: 10px;
}

.clearfix {
}

section.left {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

section.left:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(207, 168, 168, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(207, 168, 168, 1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(207, 168, 168, 1);
}


a:link {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.links:visited {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.morelink {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div id="wrap" class="col-xs-12">
    <header>
            <span class="list-style-buttons">
                <a href="#" id="listview" class="switcher"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-th-list"></i></a>
                <a href="#" id="gridview" class="switcher active"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-th"></i></a>
            </span>
    </header>
    <ul id="company" class="list clearfix">

            <li class="clearfix alt">
                <section class="left">
                    <img src="" alt="company image" class="thumb">
                    <a href="#">
                        <h3>Name</h3></a>
                    <span class="meta address"><strong>Address: </strong></span>
                    <span class="meta description">DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION 
DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION
 DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION
 DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION
 DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION 
                    </span>
                    <span id="link-list">
                    <a href=""
                       class="links"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i>
                        Users: </a>

                    <a href="" class="links secondOffer"><i class="fa fa-database"></i> Offers: </a>
                </span>
                </section>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery's data function: https://api.jquery.com/data/

> The .data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM
>   elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore
>   from memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the css `text-overflow: clip` when you're in the grid view to clip any text that doesn't fit inside of your element.

Options also include:

```
text-overflow: clip;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
text-overflow: "…";
text-overflow: fade;
text-overflow: fade(10px);
text-overflow: fade(5%);
```

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question, you want to switch between tow classes each time the button was clicked, so i prpose to use `.toggleClass()`.

Comment: This is not what OP is after, they want to show a shortened description, then restore the full description after clicking the "morelink" if I'm not mistaken.